# I launch a separate thread from a Java based AWS lambda handler, sometimes it completes and sometimes not, Why? How to ensure thread completion?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

From the handler, I launch a separate thread to update a Dynamo table where I keep count of API calls per user. Thing is, after handler completion, sometimes the database is updated and sometimes not, so I opted to do the database update using the same initial thread, and now the database is always updated, so this means that the other thread sometimes finishes and sometimes it doesn't. Does it have to do with the way lambda freezes a handler invocation when it finishes? How could I ensure the separate thread finishes before the handler container is frozen? I'm using the old Java Runnable interface and Thread class.

Comment: Please include your code in a [reprex]

Comment: AWS lambdas run until either the main thread terminates or the execution timeout is reached - but it's a little slushy. Since you're launching a new thread from your lambda's main thread, the main thread is sometimes being terminated before your secondary thread can complete. Use `Thread.join()` or execute the secondary thread's work on the main thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options to address the issue:

1. The `Java` way: Assuming you launch a new thread while the main thread is running, you can `join()` the secondary thread when the main thread finishes (i.e. just before `return`ing). Sample:

```
// Main thread executing...
Thread t = new Thread(
                 new Runnable() {
                     public void run () {
                         //do something
                     }
                  }
    );
t.start(); //Secondary thread starts
// Main thread continues execution
t.join();//Main thread will wait for the secondary to finish
return ...;
```

This will force AWS to hold the lambda instance active until after all threads are done. It will also damage your performance, since your client will only get a response after all threads finish. Which leads to the second option:

2. The AWS way: Create a new lambda function with the sole purpose to perform a single task (i.e. update DynamoDB). Invoke this function (instead of starting a new thread). You can even do that asynchronously.
   There is a good example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47155611/1505146) using [AWSLambdaAsyncClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37365009/how-to-invoke-an-aws-lambda-function-asynchronously). If you decide to go AWS way, you might as-well go via SNS:

```
    final AmazonSNSAsyncClientBuilder snsBuilder = AmazonSNSAsyncClientBuilder.standard();
    final AmazonSNS snsClient = snsBuilder.build();
    final PublishRequest pr = new PublishRequest("arn:aws:sns:logging-topic", "<JSON>");
    snsClient.publish(pr);
```

Your logging lambda can now simply listen to this SNS topic.

Comment: Could you please include a sample on how to invoke one lambda from another?

Comment: @PauloGarcía, I added links to lambda invocation answers and a sample for SNS (indirect invocation)